# Python Work Around For 'Goto'

Tags: python, goto

At the moment I have a check to see if a string has specific characters in it.

I am trying to find a work around for a 'Goto' function.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
chars = set('0123456789$,')

if any((c in chars) for c in UserInputAmount):
    print 'Input accepted'
else:
    print 'Invalid entry. Please try again'
```

I just need Python to go back to the string input of 'UserInputAmount' if the entry is invalid. A push in the right direction would be appreciate.

Comment: Go back? You mean, like, a loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a goto, you just need a loop.  Try this, which loops forever unless the user provides valid input:

```
chars = set('0123456789$,')

while True: # loop "forever"
    UserInputAmount = raw_input() # get input from user

    if any((c in chars) for c in UserInputAmount):
        print 'Input accepted'
        break # exit loop

    else:
        print 'Invalid entry. Please try again'
        # input wasn't valid, go 'round the loop again
```

Comment: Catching the EOF exception might not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

A little technique we used to call a "priming read" back when I learned Pascal:

```
chars = set('0123456789$,')

UserInputAmount = raw_input("Enter something: ")
while not any((c in chars) for c in UserInputAmount):
    UserInputAmount = raw_input("Wrong! Enter something else: ")
print "Input accepted."
```

Comment: better than mine, I didn't need the 'else'

Answer (score 2):

riffing on Ben's:

```
>>> chars = set('1234567')
>>> while not any((c in chars) for c in raw_input()):
...  print 'try again'
... else:
...  print 'accepted'
... 
abc
try again
123
accepted
```

Comment: Sure, if you want to get fancy about it. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
goodEntry = False
first = True
chars = frozenset("abc")  #whatever
validateEntry = lambda x: any( (c in chars) for c in inString)

while not goodEntry:
    if not first: print "Invalid input"
    first = False
    print "Enter input: "
    inString = raw_input()
    goodEntry = validateEntry(inString)
```

Comment: I downvoted because this seems to unnecessarily complicate things

Comment: i prefer to think of it as more generic, and I added the goodEntry flag bc I dislike using `while True` and `breaks` but whatever you say. down voting me for forgetting to set `first` to false wouldve been fair